# Javascript Recursive function not calling itself

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I want to have a live update on how many seconds have I started working on something. So I used recursive function to call itself. But however when I run, there seems to be an error as it is not updating. Following is my code:

```
        getDiff();
        function getDiff(){
                var date1 = new Date("04/06/2011");
                var d = new Date();

                var month = d.getMonth()+1;
                var day = d.getDate();

                var date2 = new Date($.now());;
                var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
                var diffDays = 0;

                // seconds
                $("#webSeconds").html(Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000))+" seconds"); 

                 setInterval(getDiff(),5000);
        }
```

As you can see, I am using setInterval but nothing is happening, any advice?

Comment: When is 04/06/2011? Is that 4 June or 6 April? Parsing strings with the Date constructor (which calls *Date.parse*) is almost entirely implementation dependent and notoriously unreliable.

Comment: What you want is `setTimeout(getDiff, 5000)` (which *schedules* the function, but does not *call* it). Notice that your current code *does* recursively call the function, unfortunately with no end.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @RobG. What would your reccomendation be?

Comment: @bergi yes thanks, that is the solution. And yes there is no end

Comment: @RickyHalim—if you wany 4 June, then `new Date(2011,5,4)` noting that months are zero indexed so 5 is June.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing the function in the `setInterval` call, don't use parenthesis after the function name. By using parenthesis, you are immediately calling the function, and passing its return value (in this case `undefined`).

```
setInterval(getDiff,5000);
//                 ^ no ()
```

This isn't limited to the use of `setInterval`, in JavaScript any time you need to pass a function as an argument or assign its reference to a variable, it shouldn't include the parenthesis.

Comment: Ahh that did the trick! Thanks! However what if i need to pass some parameters then?

Comment: To pass arguments you can use `.bind` like `getDiff.bind(this, param1, param2, param3)`.

Comment: You can pass a function like `setInterval(function(){getDiff(arg0, arg1, ...)}, interval)`. Also, calling *setInterval* recursively will start a new timer each time so after about 20 seconds there will be 4 running.